# Variables for Local Economic Environment

Tags: cross-section

I'm working on a regression to explain store sales (cross section data over a number of stores in one time frame only).  Some of my variables are 'min distance to competitor x'.  However, the results keep showing that the closer a store is to competitor x, the *higher*  sales are.  This is clearly a wrong sign, likely due to competitor x putting their stores in areas with a better economic profile.  However, every time I try to include a variable to capture local economic effects, nothing seems to fix the wrong sign (have to go at zip code level; I've tried local average tax returns, local business payroll, etc).  Any thoughts on what I could due to fix the wrong sign I'm getting here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have an endogenity problem. In this case, the most likely culprit is that the placement of the nearest competitor is endogenous (non-random), due to, as you explained above, the tendency for competitors to put their business in communities that are better off. You will need to use the instrumental variable approach as your estimation strategy to control for the endogeneity. To do this, you need to find an instrument or exclusion restriction--variable(s) related to $Minimum Distance$ that is not related to $Sales$, except through $Minimum Distance$--in your dataset. Consult the literature for instruments that have been used in your field. Your theoretical framework is also a good source of ideas for potential instruments.

Once you find a suitable instrument, you can jointly model $Sales$ and $Minimum Distance$ using instrumental variable regression, assuming your outcome is continuous, as follows:

At first stage:
$MinDist_i = Instruments_i + X + \nu_i$

At second stage:
$Sales_i  = \hat{MinDist}_i + X + \epsilon_i$

If using Stata, you can use the built-in `ivregress` command or the user-written `ivreg2` command. If using other packages, search the web for which command or package to use to run an instrumental variable regression--most statistical packages will have some IV routine either built-in or written by its users.

See Antonakis et al. (2010) for a primer on causality using non-experimental data (link in references section).  He also has a great video on endogenity on YouTube (Link: http://youtu.be/dLuTjoYmfXs).  Another good resource for IV is Khandker et al.'s (2009) *Handbook on Impact Evaluation* published by the World Bank (Ch. 6). For a more detailed treatment of the subject, see Wooldridge (2003).

**References**

1. Antonakis, J., Bendahan, S., Jacquart, P., & Lalive, R. (2010). On
   making causal claims: A review and recommendations. The Leadership
   Quarterly, 21(6), 1086–1120.
   http://doi.org/10.1016/j.leaqua.2010.10.010.  A PDF is accessible
   [here](http://www.datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/On%20making%20causal%20claims%20A%20review%20and%20recommendations.pdf) if you do not have institutional access to the journal.
2. Khandker, S., B. Koolwal, G., & Samad, H. (2009). *Handbook on
   Impact Evaluation*. Washington, DC: The World Bank.
   http://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/2693/520990PUB0EPI1101Official0Use0Only1.pdf?sequence=1
3. Wooldridge, J. M. (2003). *Introductory Econometrics: A Modern
   Approach (Vol. 2nd)*. Thomson South-Western.